# Existence of Linear Maps and the Fundamental Theorem of Linear Maps.

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that there does not exist a linear map $T: \Bbb R^5 \to \Bbb R^5$ such that $\operatorname{range}(T) = \operatorname{null} (T)$.

My proof goes like this:

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that such a linear map does exist.
Then by the fundamental theorem of linear maps we would have

$$\dim (\Bbb R^5) = \dim (\operatorname{null} (T)) + \dim (\operatorname{range} (T))$$

we know $\dim (\operatorname{null} (T))$ and $\dim (\operatorname{range} (T))$ are both subsets of $\Bbb R^5$ and therefore have $\dim$ less than or equal to five. However there are no two natural numbers less than five that are equal to each other and add up to five. Therefore such a linear map does not exist.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is exactly what I would do, though I know it as the "rank-nullity theorem" not the "fundamental theorem of linear maps" (though this has a much better ring to it).

Comment: Looks good.  Only small nitpick: dim(null($T$)) and dim(ran($T$)) are not subsets of $\Bbb{R}^5$, null($T$) and ran($T$) are sub _spaces_ of $\Bbb{R}^5$.